# How to print a variable that is tied to a word Arduino?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, arduino, random-seed

I need my Arduino code to print out random words that are substituted as a variable. So like I would have a random number generator the spits out random numbers that are tided to a word that then as a variable needs to be printed out. Here is my code now, sorry I am still a beginner to Arduino.

```
long randnumber = 0;

int aye = 1;
int sup = 2;
int boi = 3;
int bruv = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication

}

void loop() {
int randnumber = 0;
  randnumber = random(0,4);
  Serial.println(randnumber);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the words into an array:

```
const char *words[] = {"aye", "sup", "boi", "bruv"};
```

Then pick a random index and send the word at that index:

```
// Calculate the number of words. Better than hardcoding
// 4. If you add/remove words from array, this code
// won't have to change
int num_words = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);
randnumber = random(0, num_words);
Serial.println(words[randnumber]);
```

You should also seed the RNG else you will get the same results each time. On a PC, people often seed the RNG with the current time, but there is no clock on the Arduino so it is more difficult. Here's a good discussion on that: [Getting a truly random number in Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/50671/getting-a-truly-random-number-in-arduino).

Comment: the question you link is about getting true randomness as opposed to pseudo randomness, while picking a seed for a prng does not make it less pseudo. Not saying that you wrote anything wrong, just that it could be misunderstood as being able to get getting true randomness from a prng if you just pick a good seed

Comment: @user463035818 True. I just included the link since some of the answers address picking a good seed. `randomSeed(analogRead(0))` is probably sufficient for this application.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Hey thank you so much for the quick and awesome answer. I posted this at 1 in the morning and when I woke up my question has been answered, soo awesome. Will try to implement it in my code now. ;-)))